# terminating a tail -f command in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

i have the following script. i want to break the tail -f command using the ENTER key. but it is not working :\ please help.

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
while true 
do
read -s -n 1 key  
if [[ $key == $'\x0a' ]]
then
    #id=$(pidof tail) 
    #sudo kill -9 $id 
        
    
    fi
done
```

also tried this and but not working as well

```
while ! tail -f /var/log/auth.log
do
read -s -N 1 -t 1 key
if [[ $key == $'\x0a' ]];        # if input == ENTER key
then
    id=$(pidof tail)
    sudo kill -9 $id      
fi
done
```

Comment: First example: The `while true` doesn't even _start_ until after `tail -f` exited, so _of course_ it can't stop it. Second example: the body of the loop (the `read`) _likewise_ doesn't start until after `tail -f` exits, so same issue.

Comment: Note that using `pidof tail` is a really bad idea here; how do you know it'll find _your_ copy of tail, and not one being run for a different reason in a completely different terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rest of your script to operate while the `tail` is still going, you need to put the `tail` in the background. Using `&` does this.

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log & tail_pid=$!  # store PID of tail in $tail_pid
read _                                   # read until there's a carriage return
kill "$tail_pid"                         # end the tail_pid process
```

Comment: how can i attach the tail -f /var/log/auth.log with terminating it with a key pressing?

Comment: The answer already shows you how. `read` blocks until the user presses enter, so the kill command below it doesn't happen until the user has pressed the key.

Comment: i meant, How can i terminate it with different key, not ENTER? lets say the "E" key

Comment: Nothing specific to tail about that; "how do I loop until the user presses a specific key in bash?" is something that should be its own, separate question. (And it almost certainly is one already). Moreover, your code was broken _specifically_ for the enter case (because enter is the default for the `-d` argument to read, so it'll never be present in the returned value unless you override that default), but it could well already work for `E` exactly as you had it.